# google docs to docx перенос меню с контрольным списком (галочки)

Tags: ms-word, google-docs, перенос

есть контрольный список в гугл документе, но при сохранении в word (docx) 2021 года галочки пропадают и остается просто список

как его перенести с сохранением полей? уже без возможности выбора понятное дело, а просто с полями галочек

Comment: Хоть бы ссылку дали или скрин показали, а то ничего не понятно